# Why does sscanf changing the value of original char array?

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings

I'm not understand how sscanf works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    char s[100] = "testtes te asdf newlinetest";

    char parm1[10];
    char parm2[4];
    char parm3[256];
    char parm4[10];

    printf("BEFORE: %s\n", s);
    sscanf(s, "%s %s %s %s", parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4);
    printf("AFTER: %s\n", s);

    return (0);
}
```

Output :

```
BEFORE: testtes te asdf newlinetest
AFTER: t
```

It seems like it is printing the last character, however when the size of parm1 to 90, it prints the correct output.

Output:

```
BEFORE: testtes te asdf newlinetest
AFTER: testtes te asdf newlinetest
```

Comment: `parm4` does not have enough space for the 4th word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`param4` is not large enough to hold the string "newlinetest".  As a result, when `sscanf` writes to it it writes past the end of the array.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In this *particular* case, it just so happened that `s` appeared immediately after `param4` in memory so the first few bytes of `s` were overwritten.  However, this is only one way the program could have behaved.  It could have appeared to work properly.

By making `param4` larger, you prevent writing past the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough space in `parm4` to hold `"newlinetest"`.  `parm4` can hold 10 characters, but `"newlinetest"` is 11 characters long, plus you need an additional character for the null character, so you need 12 characters to hold it.  After writing the first 10 characters to `parm4`, it keeps going, writing `t` and `\0` to the memory that follows `parm4`, which in this case is apparently `s`.  So `s` ends up holding `"t"`.

Note that this is undefined behavior, and you can't count on it behaving this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a memory overwriting because the following  array is declared with only `10` characters like

```
char parm4[10];
```

and you are trying to write to it the string `"newlinetest"` that contains `12` characters including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Declare the array at least with `12` characters

```
char parm4[12];
```

and you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said in the answers, when you use `sscanf()` to parse a string, better use a width modifier:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[100] = "testtes te asdf newlinetest";

    char parm1[10];
    char parm2[4];
    char parm3[256];
    char parm4[12]; // 12 since your last word contains 11 characters (+1 for \0)

    printf("BEFORE: %s\n", s);
    sscanf(s, "%9s %3s %255s %11s", parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4);
    printf("AFTER: %s\n", s);
}
```

Your output should look like this:

```
BEFORE: testtes te asdf newlinetest
AFTER: testtes te asdf newlinetest
```